# Chef-solo run_list error with JSON

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

First try at spinning up a vagrant VM with chef-solo. Now encountering an error due to my node.json file others have tried to [address on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132516/vagrant-requires-attributes-in-roles-json-that-break-existing-chef-project) a couple of [times before](https://serverfault.com/questions/411752/going-from-vagrant-in-development-to-chef-solo-in-production-and-getting-a-fat?rq=1). The VM is an Ubuntu 12.04 both the workstation and node are running 10.16.2.

Here is the node.json:

```
{
  "name": "apptron",
  "description": "slightly complicated config",
  "chef_type": "role",
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
  "default_attributes": {},
  "env_run_lists": {
     "_default": [],
     "production": [],
     "staging": [],
     "test": [],
     "monitoring": [],
     "queuing": []
  },
 "run_list": ["recipe[base]", "recipe[user]"],
 "override_attributes": {}
}
```

On the node the stacktrace:

```
vagrant@web:~$ sudo chef-solo -l debug
[2012-11-03T02:51:08+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 10.16.2 ***
[2012-11-03T02:51:08+00:00] DEBUG: Building node object for web
[2012-11-03T02:51:08+00:00] DEBUG: Extracting run list from JSON attributes provided on command line
[2012-11-03T02:51:08+00:00] DEBUG: Re-raising exception: NoMethodError - undefined method `delete' for role[apptron]:Chef::Role
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/node.rb:407:in `consume_run_list'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/node.rb:392:in `consume_attributes'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/node.rb:380:in `consume_external_attrs'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/client.rb:252:in `build_node'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/client.rb:412:in `do_run'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/client.rb:176:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application.rb:140:in `run_chef_client'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:224:in `block in run_application'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:216:in `loop'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:216:in `run_application'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application.rb:72:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/chef-solo:23:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/chef-solo:23:in `<main>'
[2012-11-03T02:51:08+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/chef-stacktrace.out
[2012-11-03T02:51:08+00:00] DEBUG: NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for role[apptron]:Chef::Role
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/node.rb:407:in `consume_run_list'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/node.rb:392:in `consume_attributes'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/node.rb:380:in `consume_external_attrs'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/client.rb:252:in `build_node'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/client.rb:412:in `do_run'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/client.rb:176:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application.rb:140:in `run_chef_client'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:224:in `block in run_application'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:216:in `loop'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:216:in `run_application'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application.rb:72:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/chef-solo:23:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/chef-solo:23:in `<main>'
[2012-11-03T02:51:08+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for role[apptron]:Chef::Role
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem lie in the `node.json` key `json_class: "Chef::Role"` for some reason when I apply this, I get the strange error. When I do not, everything runs as expected on Vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

You were putting role json data into a node json file, which is what caused this problem.

This bit:

```
"chef_type": "role",
"json_class": "Chef::Role",
```

belongs in a role json.

In my case I had node json data in a role json, and the role json data in a node json... herp derp :)